# docker exec error "/data # ^[[2;9R" when try get shell or ash

Tags: docker, docker-exec

when I'm executing a command in docker to get container bash, I'm faced with such a message and I can not enter any commands

```
docker exec -u 0  -t  my_local_redis ash
```

and error is:

```
/data # ^[[2;9R
```

but when I run the below command it seems ok

```
docker exec -u 0  -t  my_local_redis ls
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using interactive terminal mode
`docker exec -u 0  -it  my_local_redis ash`

Comment: Thanks .. my problem is solved. But what was the problem?